# How to use a where clause on a sub navigation property using linq and EF

Tags: c#, linq

My model has a navigation property and this navigation property has another sub navigation property. I need to use a `where clause` on sub navigation property to filter results.

I'm trying to use linq query but unable to get the results

`_context.Set<Job>().Include(x=>x.Premises).ThenInclude(y=>y.Station.Where(s=>s.)`

The following sql join gives me desired results

```
select * 
  from [dbo].[JOB] J inner join 
       [dbo].[PREMISES] P on J.PremisesId = P.Id inner join 
       [dbo].[STATION] S on P.StationCode=S.StationCode
 where S.StationCode = '001'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please show the navigation properties. Are any of them collections?

Answer (score 1):

Notice these similar LINQ statements:

```
var jobs = db.Jobs
                .Include(j => j.Premises)
                .Include(j => j.Premises.Select(p => p.Stations))
                .ToList();

var stations = db.Stations
                .Include(s => s.Premise)
                .Include(s => s.Premise.Job)
                .ToList();
```

While your return type is different, you are essentially holding the same data in memory. I could use the second to get all jobs too:

```
var jobs_from_stations = stations.Select(s => s.Premise.Job).Distinct();
```

Both `jobs_from_stations` and `jobs` will contain the exact same data.

**There is a difference in filtering though.**

If you were to add a `Where()` clause in this query, it would work differently.

The first query would filter in scope of the `Job` entity, whereas the second would filter in scope of the `Station` entity.
Since you are currently trying to filter based on a station property, that suggests using the second query:

```
var stations = db.Stations
                .Include(s => s.Premise)
                .Include(s => s.Premise.Job)
                .Where(s => s.StationCode == "001")
                .ToList();
```

If you want the return type to be a list of jobs:

```
var jobs = db.Stations
                .Include(s => s.Premise)
                .Include(s => s.Premise.Job)
                .Where(s => s.StationCode == "001")
                .Select(s => s.Premise.Job)
                .Distinct()
                .ToList();
```

Note that it would still be possible to use the first query instead, but it becomes more verbose and unwieldy:

```
var jobs = db.Jobs
                .Include(j => j.Premises)
                .Include(j => j.Premises.Select(p => p.Stations))
                .Where(j => j.Premises.Any(p => p.Stations.Any(s => s.StationCode == "001")))
                .ToList();
```

---

As a rule of thumb, I always try to **start from the child** and work my way up. As you see in the above example, it makes the filtering easier. But maybe you also noticed that it keeps the `Include()` statements simple too:

```
.Include(s => s.Premise)
.Include(s => s.Premise.Job)
```

instead of

```
.Include(j => j.Premises)
.Include(j => j.Premises.Select(p => p.Stations))
```

While these two examples are functionally equivalent, having to add a `Select()` for every level becomes very cumbersome if you want to include entities that are several relationships removed from where you started.